# How to change turtlebot gazebo FOV and make it 270 degree?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am trying to change the settings of turtlebot  simulation, so I can get a better gmapping result.
But I can't find a better way to change FOV of kinect. Any help is much appreciated.

I went to the turtlebot_description folder and find the urdf file of turtlebot_gazebo.urdf.xarco.
I modified the following code.

<horizontal_fov>${60.0*M_PI/180.0}</horizontal_fov>

I edited horizontal_fov to change its FOV. If I change it like {160.0*M_PI/180.0}, the result of gmapping can be shown on rviz tool;  but if I change horizontal_fov to more than {180.0*M_PI/180.0}, the gmapping result will not be shown.

I have been looking everywhere but I can't find where I can remove the restriction and make simulated Kinect have a FOV of 270 degree. I wonder if there is a solution?

Thank you very much for helping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232564/how-to-change-turtlebot-gazebo-fov-and-make-it-270-degree?/) by [Sean81](https://answers.ros.org/users/26666/sean81/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simulated kinect uses a pinhole camera model. This model only works for FOVs below 180 degree, so there is no way you can over 180 without some major refactoring. There is a wide angle camera available for Gazebo (see [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=wide_angle_camera&branch=wideanglecamera)), but making this work for depth images might be significant implementation effort.

You're probably better off just mounting a simulated LIDAR to your Turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sean81](https://answers.ros.org/users/26666/sean81/) on 2016-04-22**:
Thank you!!! I will try to use a simulated laser scanner.